# i use @ApplicationScoped but i've found 2 instance

Tags: glassfish, java-ee-6, session-scope

I've a list of users used, with a managed bean noted with @ApplicationScoped; The problème is when i check my list i've founded something weird.
there is a difference between when i access with the both adresses ::
localhost:8080/myAPP and 127.0.0.1:8080/myAPP

Comment: From which package are you importing the annotation?

Comment: From `import javax.faces.bean.ApplicationScoped;`
And i don't went to use a singleton EJB

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by importing from the wrong package. If you try a refresh on either `localhost:8080/myAPP` or `127.0.0.1:8080/myAPP` you should see that the bean instance changes everytime, even on the same hostname.

You have to import `javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped` to make it work.

**See also:**

- [JSF application scope instantiation and injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14172764/jsf-application-scope-instantiation-and-injection)
- [Why are there different bean management annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057564/why-are-there-different-bean-management-annotations)
- [Java EE 6 @javax.annotation.ManagedBean vs. @javax.inject.Named vs. @javax.faces.ManagedBean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11986847/java-ee-6-javax-annotation-managedbean-vs-javax-inject-named-vs-javax-faces)

Comment: the matter is : i dont want to change it every time, but to be the **same** for each  refresh on the both instance.

Comment: I have a managed bean noted with @ApplicationScoped, i want to solve this problem (see the pictures attached);
NOW : _https://www.dropbox.com/s/qj9kr7a6u7xpnxa/now.png_
The GOAL : _https://www.dropbox.com/s/fz6ry5jchbq9tu7/goal.png_

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Comment: Yes, i have try it; With your solution, the data (of each page) are refreshed when i load the page on each instance.

Comment: I need the same data on the both instances.

Comment: This should be the case....did you remove the old import when you added the new one?

Comment: Absolutely. The question is should me use the both together:
`import javax.annotation.ManagedBean;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;`

Comment: None of them, you only need `javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped`.